# Tab navigation does not work using Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have this HTML page

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Excel Viewer</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="fileTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link active" id="excel-tab1" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#excel1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="excel1" aria-selected="true">9. Defined Data Objects.xlsx</button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link" id="excel-tab2" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#excel2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="excel2" aria-selected="false">9. Defined Data Objects_2.xlsx</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="excel1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="excel1">
                    <br>
                    <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="data1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="text-align: right;">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Data Attribute</th>
                                <th>Default Expression</th>
                                <th>Override Expression</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ACCT_AMT_AVLBL_AFTR_PRCG_NMRC</td>
                                <td>decimal128(18, 0)</td>
                                <td>pydecimal(left_digits=18,right_digits=0)</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="excel2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="excel2">
                    <br>
                    <table border="1" class="dataframe table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="data2">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="text-align: right;">
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Data Attribute</th>
                                <th>Default Expression</th>
                                <th>Override Expression</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>ACCT_AMT_AVLBL_AFTR_PRCG_NMRC</td>
                                <td>decimal128(18, 0)</td>
                                <td>pydecimal(left_digits=18,right_digits=0)</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                for (let i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
                    $(`#data` + i).DataTable();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I was trying to enable tabs via JavaScript like here

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

but it did not work.

What do I miss?

Comment: I quote first line on page "Use the tab JavaScript plugin—include it individually or through the compiled bootstrap.js file—to extend our navigational tabs and pills to create tabbable panes of local content."

Comment: It doesn't look like you imported bootstrap.js

Comment: You really should update the library. Version 5.0 is very old. Also, don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use [margin or padding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding).

Comment: Yeah,I thought that I had bootstrap.js (via datatables) but I did not realize that it was not included. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a problem since you are utilising the data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target properties, which are exclusive to the JavaScript-based components of Bootstrap 5. The JavaScript files for Bootstrap 5 are not included in your HTML page, nevertheless. The two JavaScript files shown below must be added to your HTML page in order to resolve this problem:
I don't know if I'm correct but try

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Bz5HvUS0fQZyOaRKVYlD/GeGQw+l+X5W7wzhrbUddDfJN/8kj9J9OVhS9M0Eu9UH" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

you can try to add this and see if it works